# Convert System.Windows.Media.Brush to System.Drawing.Brush

Tags: c#, brush

How can I convert a System.Windows.Media.Brush to System.Drawing.Brush?

I'm trying to get the color of a system.windows.media.brush formatted to a  System.Drawing.Color object.

The below solution doesn't work because it requires a solidcolorbrush object, whereas the object i need converting from is a system.windows.media.brush object:

```
public System.Drawing.Color GetColor( System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush oBrush )
{
   return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb( oBrush.Color.A,
                                     oBrush.Color.R,
                                     oBrush.Color.G,
                                     oBrush.Color.B );
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you can just cast it as a SolidColorBrush to get the color.

Try something like:

```
MyColor = ((SolidColorBrush)MyMediaBrush).Color;
```

Comment: You really should do a direct cast otherwise if the cast fails you'll get a confusing null reference exception instead of a more descriptive invalid cast exception.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I was under the assumption that the two methods only differed in syntax. This is great to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
   System.Drawing.Color c1 = new System.Drawing.Color();
            c1 = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Properties.Settings.Default.myColor);
            System.Windows.Media.Color c2 = new Color();
            c2 = Color.FromArgb(c1.A, c1.R, c1.G, c1.B);
```