# How do I convert System.Windows.Media.SolidcolorBrush to System.Drawing.Color?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I need to convert a System.Windows.Media.SolidcolorBrush to a System.Drawing.Color in C# any clues would be great.

Comment: just have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046301/convert-system-windows-media-brush-to-system-drawing-brush

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`SolidColorBrush.Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.color.aspx) to get or set the colour. This is a [`System.Windows.Media.Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.aspx) which has A, R, G, B properties.

You can then use those values when creating your [`System.Drawing.Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx)

```
System.Drawing.Color myColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(mediaColor.Color.A,
                                                             mediaColor.Color.R,
                                                             mediaColor.Color.G,
                                                             mediaColor.Color.B);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    private System.Drawing.Color WpfBrushToDrawingColor(System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush br)
    {
        return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(
            br.Color.A,
            br.Color.R,
            br.Color.G,
            br.Color.B);
    }
```