# set background-color with razor

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, razor

I have cshtml with with Model, which has list of elements and each element has SolidBrushColor field. I created separate field to return hex string of this color. How can I set background-color of td elements using this field "ColorName"?

```
@foreach (var b in Model.List)
        {
        <tr>
            <td  style="background:@b.func.ColorName;">@b.func.UniqueId</td>
            <td>@b.quantity</td>
            <td>@b.func.Name</td>
            @foreach (var i in b.func.Products)
            {

                <td>@i.Name</td>
                <td>@i.Type</td>
            }

        </tr>
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color)` to convert it into *HTML string color representation*.

Refer [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.colortranslator.tohtml?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_ColorTranslator_ToHtml_System_Drawing_Color_)

Note that, this method takes `System.Drawing.Color` as parameter. So, you can either pass the color in `System.Drawing.Color` or if that is not possible then convert `SolidBrushColor` to `System.Drawing.Color`.

See: [How do I convert System.Windows.Media.SolidcolorBrush to System.Drawing.Color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457680/how-do-i-convert-system-windows-media-solidcolorbrush-to-system-drawing-color)