# C# how to convert system.windows.media.brush to system.drawing.brush

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I am trying to add a watermark for a TextBox. The TextBox.Background is a System.Windows.Media.Brush. I need the Graphics.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brush....)

Is there any way to convert the mediea brush to the drawing brush?

Comment: I don't think so. They are two completely incompatible things based on two largely incompatible frameworks.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046301/convert-system-windows-media-brush-to-system-drawing-brush

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with this

```
System.Drawing.Brush b = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush((System.Drawing.Color)new System.Drawing.ColorConverter().ConvertFromString(new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter().ConvertToString(mediabrush)));
```

Comment: Hi Sam, may I also ask how to change a hex color to a System.Drawing.Brushes?

Comment: try this `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("hexcolor");` or also as i have done `(System.Drawing.Color)new System.Drawing.ColorConverter().ConvertFromString("hexcolor");` for convert the color

Answer (score 1):

This will also work for UWP and WinUI. Usage:

```cs
var newBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(brush.ToSystemDrawingColor())
```

```cs
internal static System.Drawing.Color ToSystemDrawingColor(this Brush? brush)
{
    if (brush == null)
    {
        return System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
    }

    if (brush is not SolidColorBrush solidColorBrush)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    var color = solidColorBrush.Color;

    return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(
        alpha: color.A,
        red: color.R,
        green: color.G,
        blue: color.B);
}
```